# Issue in configuring debmirror

Tags: ubuntu, repository, debian-installer

Getting error in debmirror.

```
Getting meta files ...
[  0%] Getting: dists/xenial/Release...          #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/Release ==> 500 Can't connect to localhost:3128 (Connection refused)
failed 500 Can't connect to localhost:3128 (Connection refused)
[  0%] Getting: dists/xenial-updates/Release...          #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/Release ==> 500 Can't connect to localhost:3128 (Connection refused)
failed 500 Can't connect to localhost:3128 (Connection refused)
[  0%] Getting: dists/xenial-security/Release...         #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/Release ==> 500 Can't connect to localhost:3128 (Connection refused)
failed 500 Can't connect to localhost:3128 (Connection refused)
Errors:
 Download of dists/xenial/Release failed: 500 Can't connect to localhost:3128 (Connection refused)
 Download of dists/xenial-updates/Release failed: 500 Can't connect to localhost:3128 (Connection refused)
 Download of dists/xenial-security/Release failed: 500 Can't connect to localhost:3128 (Connection refused)
Failed to download some Release or Release.gpg files!
```

Debmirror configuration

```
# cat /etc/debmirror.conf  | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^$
 $mirrordir="/home/unni/multiverse";
$verbose=0;
$progress=0;
$debug=0;
$host="archive.ubuntu.com";
$download_method="http";
@dists="xenial";
$omit_suite_symlinks=0;
$skippackages=0;
$i18n=0;
$getcontents=0;
$do_source=0;
$max_batch=0;
$state_cache_days=0;
$ignore_release_gpg=0;
$ignore_release=0;
$check_md5sums=0;
$ignore_small_errors=0;
$cleanup=0;
$post_cleanup=1;
$timeout=500;
$rsync_batch=200;
$rsync_options="-aIL --partial";
$passive=0;
 $proxy="http://localhost:3128/";
$dry_run=0;
$diff_mode="use";
1;
```

Sync script

```
#cat 01-get-multiverse.sh  | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^$
arch=i386,amd64
section=multiverse
release=xenial-updates,xenial-security
server=archive.ubuntu.com
inPath=/ubuntu
proto=http
outPath=/home/unni/multiverse/
echo "`date +%x-%R` - $pid - MULTIVERSE SYNC STARTED"
debmirror       --no-check-gpg \
                --ignore-release-gpg \
                -a $arch \
                --nosource \
                --cleanup \
                -s $section \
                -d $release \
                -h $server \
                -r $inPath \
                -e $proto \
                --exclude=multiverse/a \
                --exclude=multiverse/b \
                --exclude=multiverse/c \
                --exclude=multiverse/d \
                --exclude=multiverse/e \
                --exclude=multiverse/f \
                --exclude=multiverse/g \
                --exclude=multiverse/h \
                --exclude=multiverse/i \
                --exclude=multiverse/j \
                --exclude=multiverse/k \
                --exclude=multiverse/l \
                --exclude=multiverse/lib* \
                --exclude=multiverse/m \
                --exclude=multiverse/n \
                --exclude=multiverse/o \
                --exclude=multiverse/p \
                --exclude=multiverse/q \
                --exclude=multiverse/r \
                --exclude=multiverse/s \
                --exclude=multiverse/t \
                --exclude=multiverse/u \
                --exclude=multiverse/v \
                --exclude=multiverse/w \
                --include=multiverse/w/wine* \
                --exclude=multiverse/x \
                --exclude=multiverse/y \
                --exclude=multiverse/z \
                --include=Packages \
                --progress \
                $outPath
echo "`date +%x-%R` - $pid - MULTIVERSE SYNC COMPLETED"
```

Comment: Do you actually have a web proxy at `http://localhost:3128/`?  If you do, then the proxy isn't working or isn't accepting local connections, as the errors indicate.

Comment: @ThomasWard thanks for the suggestion..

cntlm is running on the machine

`# service cntlm status
 * cntlm is running`

# telnet localhost 3128
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved.

**$proxy="http://localhost:3128/"**

in the debmirror.conf,

has been changed to

**$proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"**

Now debmirror is connecting through proxy.

Strange ...